# How to disable/enable kendo-daterange programmatically? (without JQuery)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, kendo-ui, kendo-datepicker

I have the following template
[image]

and it works fine. The daterange is disabled. But if I remove these inline "disabled" attributes and if I want to disable/enable it via the button click programmatically, it doesn't work even though "disabled" attribute will be added into the elements.
[image]

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use property binding syntax instead of using `toggleAttribute`:

Something like this:

```
<kendo-dateinput ... [disabled]="somePropertyOnYourComponent" ></kendo-dateinput>
```

And then in `test`:

```
test() {
  ...
  somePropertyOnYourComponent = true;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks. But I wanted to avoid using inline attributes or property binding.

Answer (score 0):

The approach with property binding works fine but if for whatever reason you want to use plain JS (TS) you need to disable/enable 4 elements (2 kendo-dateinput and 2 autogenerated by kendo internal inputs)
[image]